# How do you force Duration.FromText to recognize a particular supported format?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, m

Greetings beloved comrades,

I have duration data in the text format `HHHH:MM:SS`.

When I use the Duration.FromText() function, it converts `3873:05:43` to `3873.05:42:00`, which is incorrect.

It returns an error on `4161:51:05`, and on all values where the center segment is greater than 30.

According to the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt253538.aspx)  `[-]hh:mm[:ss]` is a valid format option, but it gives no hints as to how to apply the format mask so that the text is parsed correctly.

How do I get Duration.FromText() to correctly interpret `3873:05:43`?

Comment: Hi, hh:mm:ss doesn't mean hh can be more than 23 hours, the reason it worked and took the 4 digit number as days is because of the way .NET 4.0 and 4.5 works. We're changing our behavior to always work like 3.5, this means "3873:05:43" will not work at all in future PQ updates. I recommend splitting by ":" and creating duration value, probably Max Zelensky's answer can help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like `Duration.FromText("0.3873:05:43")` should *just work* and return the same value as `#duration(0, 3873, 05, 43)`.

I'll add this to our bug backlog. Sorry that you ran into this problem!

Without looking at the code I'm less clear what's happening with `3873:05:43`. We can either fix the function or update the documentation.

---

Update (from a year ago): we discussed this back-and-forth internally, and decided to document the allowable ranges:

> The following formats can be parsed by this function:
>
> ```
> (-)hh:mm(:ss(.ff))
> (-)ddd(.hh:mm(:ss(.ff)))
> ```
>
> - ddd: Number of days.
> - hh: Number of hours, between 0 and 23.
> - mm: Number of minutes, between 0 and 59.
> - ss: Number of seconds, between 0 and 59.
> - ff: Fraction of seconds, between 0 and 9999999.
>
> (All ranges are inclusive)

This new documentation has been released in Power Query / Power BI Desktop, and it will make it to MSDN... sometime...

Answer (score 2):

If in one row, you can do it this way:

```
TransfromDur = Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Column1", each #duration(0,Number.From(Text.Split(_,":"){0}),Number.From(Text.Split(_,":"){1}),Number.From(Text.Split(_,":"){2})), type duration}})
```

And you'll get 161.09:05:43 from 3873:05:43

The idea is in parsing your text to hours, minutes and seconds by splitting it by ":" symbol, and then feed the result to #duration(days,hours,minutes,seconds)

AFAIK, this notation [-]hh:mm[:ss] allows only two digits for hour when converting it to duration.

Or you can do it in several steps:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="dftext"]}[Content],
    SplitIt = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, {{"Column1", type text}}),"Column1",Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":"),{"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3"}),
    ChangeType = Table.TransformColumnTypes(SplitIt,{{"Column1.1", Int64.Type}, {"Column1.2", Int64.Type}, {"Column1.3", Int64.Type}}),
    AddDur = Table.AddColumn(ChangeType, "Column1", each #duration(0,[Column1.1],[Column1.2],[Column1.3])),
    RemCols = Table.RemoveColumns(AddDur,{"Column1.1", "Column1.2", "Column1.3"})
in
    RemCols
```